# Values in Many-to-Many field not getting selected when editing an object in a custom(Non-admin) Django view

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, many-to-many

We have a django-model containing a many-to-many field. We use the same form to add/edit objects. When an existing object is loaded for editing all fields have values associated with them **except the Many-to-Many field(None of the options is the MultipleSelectBox Widget are selected)**

Is there any special way to bind values to Many-to-Many field so that the the current values of the field appear selected in the MultipleSelectBox Widget when the form loads the object for editing.

I tried reading up similar questions put up by users on SO, but couldn't find the answer to my query :(.

Comment: It is really hard to tell from what you write. You haven't given us any code and my magic crystal ball is refusing to work right now. How is your form defined? The form field for your ManyToMany relation? What exactly do you override? How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try To Do This!
This Is My Example To Show You How Can You Do It :D

```
class FirstModel(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 100, unique = True)

class SecondModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 100, unique = True)
    first_model = models.ManyToManyField(FirstModel)

class MyForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(max_length = 100, required = True)
    first_model = forms.ChoiceField(widget = forms.MultipleSelect)
```

After You save It In Your add Function, Then To Edit It In edit Function, Do This:

```
def edit(request):
    my_model = MyModel.objects.filter(name = 'You Unique Name').get()
    first_model = my_model.first_model.all()
    my_form = MyForm(initial = {'first_model': first_model})
```

That's It :D

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem, and it was caused by `commit=False`.  The way to fix it is with `save_m2m()`

```
# Create a form instance with POST data.
f = AuthorForm(request.POST)
# Create, but don't save the new author instance.
new_author = f.save(commit=False)
# Modify the author in some way.
new_author.some_field = 'some_value'
# Save the new instance.
new_author.save()
# Now, save the many-to-many data for the form.
f.save_m2m()
```